# Inserting null value into oracle using cx_oracle template

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Hi I am trying to insert a Null value in one of the table in my oracle database but failed.

I am using the execute method (from cx_oracle library) to insert the value:

> cur.execute(q, payload)

where **q** is the query template and **payload** is the dictionary consists of the values to insert.

I expected when the value in **payload** is None, a null value will be inserted in the corresponding field.

Yet instead of a successful insertion, I received the following error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Can anyone tell me what is the proper way to insert null value into oracle via the execute method of cx_oracle?

Comment: Can you show us the actual raw query which was executed?  Is that particular column set to not accept null values?

Comment: Yes, the actual values of q and payload are needed in this case to be able to answer your question. None does indeed bind to null and should work fine -- so something else is going on.